# Shorter syntax for casting from a List<X> to a List<Y>?

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

I know it's possible to cast a list of items from one type to another (given that your object has a public static explicit operator method to do the casting) one at a time as follows:

```
List<Y> ListOfY = new List<Y>();

foreach(X x in ListOfX)
    ListOfY.Add((Y)x);
```

But is it not possible to cast the entire list at one time? For example,

```
ListOfY = (List<Y>)ListOfX;
```

Comment: Presuming X derives from Y, and Z derives from Y, think what would happen if you added Z to your List<Y> which is really a List<X>.

Answer (score 625, accepted):

If `X` can really be cast to `Y` you should be able to use

```
List<Y> listOfY = listOfX.Cast<Y>().ToList();
```

Some things to be aware of (H/T to commenters!)

- You must include `using System.Linq;` to get this extension method
- This casts each item in the list - not the list itself. A new `List<Y>` will  be created by the call to `ToList()`.
- This method does not support custom conversion operators. ( see [Why does the Linq Cast<> helper not work with the implicit cast operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523530/why-does-the-linq-cast-helper-not-work-with-the-implicit-cast-operator) )
- This method does not work for an object that has an explicit operator method (framework 4.0)

Comment: Have another gold badge. This was quite useful.

Comment: I had to google H/T btw. I've never seen that before in my life

Comment: Yeah "H/T" is "Hat tipping", or thanking basically.

Answer (score 116):

The direct cast `var ListOfY = (List<Y>)ListOfX` is not possible because it would require [co/contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) of the `List<T>` type, and that just can't be guaranteed in every case. Please read on to see the solutions to this casting problem.

While it seems normal to be able to write code like this:

```
List<Animal> animals = (List<Animal>) mammalList;
```

because we can guarantee that every mammal will be an animal, this is obviously a mistake:

```
List<Mammal> mammals = (List<Mammal>) animalList;
```

since not every animal is a mammal.

However, using C# 3 and above, you can use

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = mammalList.Cast<Animal>();
```

that eases the casting a little. This is syntactically equivalent to your one-by-one adding code, as it uses an explicit cast to cast each `Mammal` in the list to an `Animal`, and will fail if the cast is not successfull.

If  you like more control over the casting / conversion process, you could use the `ConvertAll` method of the `List<T>` class, which can use a supplied expression to convert the items. It has the added benifit that it returns a `List`, instead of `IEnumerable`, so no `.ToList()` is necessary.

```
List<object> o = new List<object>();
o.Add("one");
o.Add("two");
o.Add(3);

IEnumerable<string> s1 = o.Cast<string>(); //fails on the 3rd item
List<string> s2 = o.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString()); //succeeds
```

Comment: I cant believe ive never +1'd this answer until now. Its so much better than mine above.

Comment: @Jamiec I didn't +1 because he starts with "No, it's not possible", while burying the answer many who find this question are looking for. Technically, he did answer the OP's question more thoroughly though.

Answer (score 16):

**To add to Sweko's point:**

The reason why the cast

```
var listOfX = new List<X>();
ListOf<Y> ys = (List<Y>)listOfX; // Compile error: Cannot implicitly cast X to Y
```

is not possible is because the `List<T>` is **invariant in the Type T** and thus it doesn't matter whether `X` derives from `Y`) - this is because `List<T>` is defined as:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T> ... // Other interfaces
```

(Note that in this declaration, type `T` here has no additional variance modifiers)

However, if mutable collections are not required in your design, an upcast on many of the immutable collections, *is possible*, e.g. provided that `Giraffe` derives from `Animal`:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = giraffes;
```

This is because `IEnumerable<T>` supports covariance in `T` - this makes sense given that `IEnumerable` implies that the collection cannot be changed, since it has no support for methods to Add or Remove elements from the collection. Note the `out` keyword in the declaration of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

([Here's further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660356/314291) for the reason why mutable collections like `List` cannot support `covariance`, whereas immutable iterators and collections can.)

**Casting with `.Cast<T>()`**

As others have mentioned, [`.Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) can be applied to a collection to project a new collection of elements casted to T, however doing so will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the cast on one or more elements is not possible (which would be the same behaviour as doing the explicit cast in the OP's `foreach` loop).

**Filtering and Casting with `OfType<T>()`**

If the input list contains elements of different, incompatable types, the potential `InvalidCastException` can be avoided by using [`.OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `.Cast<T>()`. (`.OfType<>()` checks to see whether an element can be converted to the target type, before attempting the conversion, and filters out incompatable types.)

**foreach**

Also note that if the OP had written this instead: (note the **explicit `Y y`** in the `foreach`)

```
List<Y> ListOfY = new List<Y>();

foreach(Y y in ListOfX)
{
    ListOfY.Add(y);
}
```

that the casting will also be attempted. However, if no cast is possible, an `InvalidCastException` will result.

**Examples**

For example, given the simple (C#6) class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get;  }
    protected Animal(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class Elephant :  Animal
{
    public Elephant(string name) : base(name){}
}

public class Zebra : Animal
{
    public Zebra(string name)  : base(name) { }
}
```

When working with a collection of mixed types:

```
var mixedAnimals = new Animal[]
{
    new Zebra("Zed"),
    new Elephant("Ellie")
};

foreach(Animal animal in mixedAnimals)
{
     // Fails for Zed - `InvalidCastException - cannot cast from Zebra to Elephant`
     castedAnimals.Add((Elephant)animal);
}

var castedAnimals = mixedAnimals.Cast<Elephant>()
    // Also fails for Zed with `InvalidCastException
    .ToList();
```

Whereas:

```
var castedAnimals = mixedAnimals.OfType<Elephant>()
    .ToList();
// Ellie
```

filters out only the Elephants - i.e. Zebras are eliminated.

**Re: Implicit cast operators**

Without dynamic, user defined conversion operators are only used at [compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090228/314291)*, so even if a conversion operator between say Zebra and Elephant was made available, the above run time behaviour of the approaches to conversion wouldn't change.

If we add a conversion operator to convert a Zebra to an Elephant:

```
public class Zebra : Animal
{
    public Zebra(string name) : base(name) { }
    public static implicit operator Elephant(Zebra z)
    {
        return new Elephant(z.Name);
    }
}
```

Instead, given the above conversion operator, the compiler will be able to change the type of the below array from `Animal[]` to `Elephant[]`, given that the Zebras can be now converted to a homogeneous collection of Elephants:

```
var compilerInferredAnimals = new []
{
    new Zebra("Zed"),
    new Elephant("Ellie")
};
```

**Using Implicit Conversion Operators at run time**

*As mentioned by Eric, the conversion operator can however be accessed at run time by resorting to `dynamic`:

```
var mixedAnimals = new Animal[] // i.e. Polymorphic collection
{
    new Zebra("Zed"),
    new Elephant("Ellie")
};

foreach (dynamic animal in mixedAnimals)
{
    castedAnimals.Add(animal);
}
// Returns Zed, Ellie
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried the "Using foreach() for type filtering" example using:

var list = new List<object>() { 1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, "d" };

foreach (int i in list)
    Console.WriteLine(i);

and when I run it I get "Specified cast is not valid." Am I missing something? I didn't think foreach worked this way, which is why I was trying it.

Comment: Also, it's not a reference vs. value type thing. I just tried it with a base class of 'Thing' and two derived classes: 'Person', and 'Animal'. When I do the same thing with it I get: "Unable to cast object of type 'Animal' to type 'Person'." So it's definitely iterating through each element. IF I were to do an OfType on the list then it would work. ForEach would probably be really slow if it had to check this, unless the compiler optimized it.

Comment: Thanks Brent - I was off course there. `foreach` does not filter, but using a more derived type as the iteration variable will coerce the compiler into attempting a Cast, which will fail on the first element which doesn't comply.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `List<Y>.ConvertAll<T>([Converter from Y to T]);`

Answer (score 6):

This is not quite the answer to this question, but it may be useful for some: as @SWeko said, thanks to covariance and contravariance, `List<X>` can not be cast in `List<Y>`, but `List<X>` can be cast into `IEnumerable<Y>`, and even with implicit cast.

Example:

```
List<Y> ListOfY = new List<Y>();
List<X> ListOfX = (List<X>)ListOfY; // Compile error
```

but

```
List<Y> ListOfY = new List<Y>();
IEnumerable<X> EnumerableOfX = ListOfY;  // No issue
```

The big advantage is that it does not create a new list in memory.

Comment: I like this because if you have a large source list, there is no performance hit in the beginning. Instead there is a small not noticable cast for each entry being processed by the receiver. Also no huge memory build up. perfect for processing streams.

Answer (score 1):

In case when X derives from Y you can also use `ToList<T>` method instead of `Cast<T>`

```
listOfX.ToList<Y>()
```

Answer (score 0):

items.Select(x => (Object Cast)x);

Answer (score -1):

```
dynamic data = List<x> val;  
List<y> val2 = ((IEnumerable)data).Cast<y>().ToList();
```