# Return generic object type

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

The full code for this us up on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/b5a31fb0c57dbcde4c68bca3b41996c6) I am only including the portion I think is needed to show the problem.

Execute method:

```
  public object Execute()
        {
            var request = createWebRequest();
            request.Method = this.Method;
            applyPostData(ref request);

            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.UserAgent = "generic-http-dotnet-client/3.5/v1 (gzip)";

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new HttpResponse { message = responseString };
            }
        }
```

Ok this works kind of.   However what I would like to be able to do is after the method is called cast it as the appropriate object type.

```
var response = (MetaDataResponse)request.Execute();
```

I know there should be some way possibly using generics (Wild guess) for me to json DeserializeObject the response and return it?

I ended up changing the return type of execute method to a string, and doing this.

```
public class MetaDataRequest : HttpRequestBase
    {
        public MetaDataResponse MetaDataItems { get; private set; }

        public MetaDataRequest() : base(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns"), "GET")
        {
            this.addParameter("key", "xxxx");
            var response = this.Execute();

            try
            {
                MetaDataItems =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MetaDataResponse>(response);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var resultsx = new HttpResponse { message = response };
            }
        }
    }
```

Which works but seams messy to me.  Note this project is **.Net framework 3.5** and I cant change that.  Feel free to add any other tags you can think of.

Comment: I wouldn't use code like that in production... seems like really clumsy code.

Comment: I think you could add a type parameter to `HttpRequestBase` like `HttpRequestBase<T>` and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString)` and return type of `T`

Comment: Agreed with #2. Deserialize offers just that functionality. Try this, as well, for more reading on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626315/in-c-can-you-cast-one-generic-type-to-another-whos-t-parameter-is-a-subclass

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I am new at interfaces happy to learn if you have any other ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic with class MetaDataRequest

```
class MetadataRequest<T>:HttpRequestBase
{
    public T Execute()
    {
        var request = createWebRequest();
        request.Method = this.Method;
        applyPostData(ref request);

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "generic-http-dotnet-client/3.5/v1 (gzip)";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
    }
}
```

Then, to get the object, you can call the method like so:

```
MetadataResponse responseObject = (new MetadataRequest<MetadataResponse>()).Execute();
```

In this case, you can catch the exception thrown by .Execute() as it can only return null or an instance of type T.

Edit: you can also use generic method by following [Jeremy Holovacs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39469894/5539403).

Comment: Well that worked.   If I understand this the <T> by the class name tells it what the return type is?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's how generic classes and libraries are implemented, allowing the caller to choose the return type.

Comment: I have spent the last two weeks trying to get my head around generics.  I think I am almost there.   This was the first thing I made myself without coping from someone else's tutorial.    I don't know how I have lived with out them for so long.   Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

First, the gist is not disposing its IDisposables, that's pretty sloppy.  I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
public T Execute<T>()
    {
        var request = createWebRequest();
        request.Method = this.Method;
        applyPostData(ref request);

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "generic-http-dotnet-client/3.5/v1 (gzip)";

        using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using(var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            try
            {
                var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log something with ex
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your right.  I really should get into the habit of using IDisposables.

Comment: BTW: I had to change it a little I am getting "string type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.idisposable.".  just using the streamReader then reading it into the Json works nicly