# Xamarin : casting C# List<D> to List<T>

Tags: list, xamarin, casting

I have problem with casting a list of A  to List of C assuming C is a super class of A. I try to pass List of A as a parameter to a constructor where the construct accept List of C. I can use ConvertAll but it seems like it give a new copy of the list. If I update List of A, the data in List of C won't get affected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast List<X> to List<Y>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/cast-listx-to-listy)

Comment: @Trevor: Well, not a straight dupe, but at least one of the answers explains the issue. In this case, they'd need to create their list wrapper themselves, since they want changes to be reflected in the original list