# c# How do you cast lists in .net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, casting

I am using Unity 5.5.0f3 which uses .Net 2.0

I want to cast a list like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/cast-listx-to-listy) but cannot in this version of .Net

Is there an 'old school' or 'long hand' way of doing it?

Please tell me that I don't have to create my own extension method involving loops......

Comment: You should be able to do what is mentioned in the question you posted as a link, using the `foreach` loop.Didn't that work ?

Comment: Can you share us your code so far? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can! If you mean [`Enumerable.Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.90).aspx) when you say cast then it is available in *.NET 3.5* and Unity supports that. With the example code from MS doc, I was able to compile it.

You just need to include `using System.Linq` in order to use it. When in doubt, ,you can search for other Unity Mono Compatibly functions [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html).

```
using System.Linq
...
void Start()
{
    System.Collections.ArrayList fruits = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    fruits.Add("apple");
    fruits.Add("mango");

    IEnumerable<string> query =
        fruits.Cast<string>().Select(fruit => fruit);

    foreach (string fruit in query)
    {
        Debug.Log(fruit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out that I was wrong about my unity version's .Net version. I also wasn't including linq. Thanks. I admit it was a pretty dumb question in the end.

Comment: You are not entirely wrong. Unity supports .NET 2 and supports **some** functions from .NET Net 3. Some classes and functions from .NET 3 are not supported.