# C# Converting object to List<object>

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, icollection

I need to convert a list of string to a list of object, but the thing is I am receiving this list as an object, because it's a parameter and I don't know what type it is.

This is the function that receives the parameter:

```
public static bool IsNotEmpty(object obj)
{
    if (obj is ICollection)
    {
        IList<object> collection = (IList<object>)obj; // The cast throws error here
        return IsNotEmpty(collection);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And this is the one this one uses:

```
public static bool IsNotEmpty<T>(IList<T> aList)
{
    return aList != null && aList.IsNotEmpty();
}
```

What can I do to cast it as a List of objects, so then I can pass it to the other function? (if there is a way)

Comment: Why would you want IsNotEmptyString to take an object instead of a string?

Comment: IsNotEmptyString is an awfully misleading name for that function

Comment: Sorry, I changed the function so I could display it here!
Now it's actually converting to List of string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorter syntax for casting from a List<X> to a List<Y>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/shorter-syntax-for-casting-from-a-listx-to-a-listy)

Comment: why don't you use `aList.Count >0`? [It's in the interface.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PaulF I don't think so, because I'm casting from object.

Comment: FFS, ICollection has a Count.  Just check it to be not null and that count is > 0.

Comment: I'm not sure about why I'm getting a bunch of down votes for answering the question... But my solution doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: @Svek it does. It throws the same error I'm facing, sorry.

Comment: oh... my collection was a List<object> in my test code rather than List<string>... no wonder.

Comment: @tobi - I updated the answer, although it's not very elegant. It does resolve your casting issue.

Comment: Can you show some more code regarding the source of your collection to provide greater context?  I'd like to understand why you only have an `object` and not some more strongly typed collection.  That seems like the real issue.

Comment: @tobi: ((List<string>)obj).Cast<object>().ToList() seems to return a List<object> isn't that what you want

Comment: @PaulF No, it doesn't. It throws error casting from List<string> to List<object>. I've already solved it with one of the answers given here!

Comment: Interesting - it works for me. At least you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public static bool IsNotEmpty(object obj)
    {
        var collection = obj as ICollection;
        return collection == null || collection.Count > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You are doing what we call an "XY question": you have a (wrong) solution in mind for your problem and you're asking about your wrong solution rather than seeking a solution to your actual problem.

You do not need to convert a list of string to a list of object in the first place, so there's no need to ask how to do that. The right solution to your problem is:

```
static class MyExtensions 
{
  public static bool Any(this IEnumerable sequence) 
  {
     if (sequence == null) 
       throw new ArgumentNullException ... etc ...
     if (sequence is ICollection)
       return ((ICollection)sequence).Any();
     foreach(object item in sequence)
       return true;
     return false;
   }
   public static bool Any(this ICollection collection)
   {
      if (collection == null) blah blah blah
      return collection.Count > 0;
   }
}
```

Great. Now your method is:

```
public static bool IsNotEmpty(object obj)
{
  if (obj is IEnumerable)
    return ((IEnumerable)obj).Any();
  else
    return true; 
}
```

The idea here is to first go to collection because that avoids enumerating the sequence unnecessarily. That can be expensive. But if we have a sequence that has items but is not a collection, then enumerate its first element. If we can do so successfully then it is not empty; if we cannot, then it is empty.

But more generally: the signature of your method is unfortunate. Don't get into the situation where you have an `object` in hand in the first place if you can possibly avoid it. How did you get into this situation?

Comment: The last paragraph is I think the most significant.  I'd really like to know why the OP has an `object` rather than some typed collection to work with.  I suspect that is where this issue should really be being resolved.

Comment: If you use as - IsNotEmpty will be shorter