# Creating Dictionaries of generic types

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics

In my example, I have many classes (`Orange`, `Pear`, `Apple`, ...) that extend a base class `Fruit`.

I am creating a model class that contains dictionaries of each type of `Fruit` mapped to their integer ids. I'd like to avoid making many field variables like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Orange> _oranges = new Dictionary<int, Orange>();
```

I thought I might be able to create a "generic" dictionary, in which I map other dictionaries to `Fruit` types:

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<int, Fruit>> _fruits = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<int, Fruit>>();
```

To insert into this structure, I use a method like so:

```
public void Insert(Fruit fruit)
{
    _fruits[fruit.GetType()][fruit.Id] = fruit;
}
```

The problem comes when I try to retrieve the stored values, as in this method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetFruits<T>() where T : Fruit
{
    return (IEnumerable<T>) _fruits[typeof(T)].Values.ToArray();
}
```

which would be called like `GetFruits<Orange>()`. The cast fails with this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Example.Fruit[]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Example.Orange]'.'

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to cast it using `Cast<T>`.

```
return _fruits[typeof(T)].Values.Cast<T>();
```

Using a `(IEnumerable<T>)` to cast does not work because it will cast the whole thing. You may know this already: `List<object>` can't be casted to `List<int>`. The same phenomenon happens here.

Therefore, we should use `Cast<T>`. This method will cast each element of the enumerable to the specified type, and returning the resulting enumerable.

Comment: Additionally / alternatively, you can also use [`OfType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951319/314291) to filter the type and avoid possible InvalidCast exceptions

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I wanted and I understand why my code wasn't working before :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OfType` method:

```
var _fruits = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<int, Fruit>>();

public IEnumerable<T> GetFruits<T>() where T : Fruit
{
    return _fruits.OfType<T>().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the error is because the type of `Values` in the innermost Dictionary of `_fruits` is inherently a map of the base class `Fruit`:

```
Dictionary<int, Fruit>
```

Specifically, the [Values property is defined as `ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359878(v=vs.110).aspx).

At run time, you aren't allowed you to directly recast `Values`, which is a `ICollection<Fruit>` to `IEnumerable<T>` - e.g. `IEnumerable<Orange>`.

To resolve this, you will effectively need to traverse the `Values` collection and downcast (and possibly also filter) by type.

(Even though you 'know' that your code has only allowed `Oranges` into the `fruits[typeof(Orange)]` dictionary, from the type system's perspective, the type is still `ICollection<Fruit>`)

As per the other answers, you can use any number of ways to do this casting and filtering:

- A filtered foreach, `foreach(T item in Values)`
- `.Cast<T>` - This will however throw if somehow a different Fruit is found
- `.OfType<T>` - This will exclude items of the incorrect type.

There's more detail on these approaches [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/shorter-syntax-for-casting-from-a-listx-to-a-listy/41951319#41951319)