# Casting an object to List<object> in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to add the httpcontext name property in a generic way to my objects before I save it to the database and I thought I could use the `OnActionExecuting` method to do that.

I'm using one of web api life cycle hooks `OnActionExecuting`. And I'm trying to cast the incoming parameter to `List<object>` but it keeps failing with the error saying it cannot complete the task:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {


        if (context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                var result = context;
                var actionParameter = context.ActionArguments["dtoItem"];
                List<object> collection = (List<object>)actionParameter;


                    context.ActionArguments["dtoItem"] = actionParameter;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

The error that I get for this is:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Ctrac.WebApi.Core.Models.TestModel]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5115275

Answer (score 0):

You just can't cast a type of `List<T1>` to `List<T>` even if  `T1` extends `T`.

This is by design.

Suppose that the compiler allows us to do that, think about the following code :

```
List<objects> models = new  List<TestModel>();  // suppose we can do this
var o = new {a = 1 };
var index = models.IndexOf(o);                  // now we can invoke IndexOf(o)
```

Actually, the `models` here "points to" an instance of `List<TestModel>`, which means the invocation of `models.IndexOf(o)` will eventually call the method of `List<TestModel>.IndexOf(TestModel o)` instead of the `List<object>.IndexOf(object o)` . ( Similar to [`polymorphism`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping) ).

```
List<object>    .IndexOf(object o)
                           |
                           |
                           V
List<TestModel>.IndexOf(TestModel o)
```

In other words, you're assuming the instance `o` ( whose type is `object`) can be converted to `TestModel`. Obviously, that is unsafe.

See [**Covariance and Contravariance in Generics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

**How to fix**

Simply use LINQ to cast :

```
List<object> collection = actionParameter
         .Select( m => (object) m)
         .ToList();
```