# Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I convert or cast `Generic.IList`?

Encounter this error

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to
>   'PDM.App.DTO.Product.ProductDTO'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

My Code

```
public async Task<ProductDTO> EditProduct(ProductDTO Product)
{
  var request = new GetProducts_Activity_Request { };
  var response = await GetProducts_Activity.InvokeAsync(request);
  return response.Products; 
}
```

Response class look like this

```
public class GetProducts_Activity_Response : BaseActivityResponse
{
  public IList<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: for casting one list to another you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/shorter-syntax-for-casting-from-a-listx-to-a-listy) question

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
public async Task<IList<ProductDTO>> EditProduct(ProductDTO Product)
{
  var request = new GetProducts_Activity_Request { };
  var response = await GetProducts_Activity.InvokeAsync(request);
  return response.Products; 
}
```

You have to change return type to  `Task<IList<ProductDTO>>`