# Converting or casting List<sting> to List<type> in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Looking for direct way to convert/cast all elements of `List<string>` to a list of particular type which has one string property.

Type Class with one string property:

```
 public class ClaimNumber
    {
        public string claimNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

The List I receive from webservice is in `List<string>` format.

I need to convert/cast `List<string> to List<ClaimNumber>`

Tried as multiple suggessions given in [Shorter syntax for casting from a List<X> to a List<Y>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/shorter-syntax-for-casting-from-a-listx-to-a-listy), but those did not work in above case. Please suggest the right way to achieve this.

Comment: I provided a solution below that has a fairly clear example. You should be able to modify it. It also doesn't use any for loops so keeps code rather clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply run through each element and create a new `ClaimNumber` object, populating the property.

With Linq:

```
// List<string> source = ...
List<ClaimNumber> claims = source.Select(s => new ClaimNumber { claimNumber = s }).ToList();
```

With a foreach

```
// List<string> source = ...
List<ClaimNumber> claims = new();
foreach (var s in source)
{
    claims.Add(new ClaimNumber { claimNumber = s });
}
```

Comment: LINQ is convenient, but if it was a lot of data coming back from the web service, I think I would also reach for the loop option.

Comment: @wwd in this case, the OP has stated that the source is a List, so all the data is already in memory. Either method won't make much of a difference. If there are other performance requirements then the OP would need to explain them and an answer can be better tailored.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> c1List = new List<string>();
    List<ClaimNumber> c2List = new List<ClaimNumber>();

    c1List.Add("1234");
    c1List.Add("4321");
    c1List.Add("1111");
    c1List.Add("9999");

    c2List.AddRange(c1List.Select(x => new ClaimNumber
    {
        claimNumber = x
    }));
    
}

public class ClaimNumber
{
    public string claimNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This returns:

[image]